# Jquery html() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

    var region = $('#region');

    var city = $('#city');

    var pickedRegionId = region.find(':selected').val();

    var options;

    if (pickedRegionId === '') {
        console.log('region is empty, html() and disable');
        city.html('');
        city.attr('disabled', true);
    }

    region.change(function(){
        console.log('region is changed');
        pickedRegionId = $(this).val();
        if (pickedRegionId !== '') {
            city.html('');
            console.log('loading cities');
            getCities(pickedRegionId);
        }
    });

    function getCities (regionId) {
        city.attr('disabled', true);
        city.html('<option>Loading...</option>');

        $.get(
            '/ajax/get_cities',
            'region_id='+regionId,
            function (responce) {
                if (responce.result === 'success') {
                    $(responce.cities).each(function(){
                        options += '<option value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).attr('city')+'</option>';
                    });
                    city.html(options);
                    city.attr('disabled', false);
                }
            }, 'json'
        );
    }
});
```

When page loads all is ok, I pick some region and select with cities fills with ajax data.
But when I pick another region, data in cities select just extends with newer data.

So the problem that I have cities from both regions(new and old one). And not matter how many times I pick another region it's just adding new data to city select. In the code all looks fine and on region change I've put .html('') so it should be empty before inserting received values. But I can't figure out what the bug is.

Comment: Don't you just need to reinitialize the "option" value before the $(responce.cities).each statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(responce.cities).each(function(){
    options += '<option value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).attr('city')+'</option>';
});
```

You are just appending to options and not clearing it at all. I would empty your options just below where you set `cities` to loading.

Answer (score 0):

try reseting your "options" var before the loop:

```
...
options = '';
$(responce.cities).each(function(){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to empty the variable options first. You're just adding new cities to the options variable.

The simplest solution would be to move the options variable into the getCities function like this:

```
function getCities (regionId) {
    var options = "";

    city.attr('disabled', true);
    city.html('<option>Loading...</option>');

    $.get(
        '/ajax/get_cities',
        'region_id='+regionId,
        function (responce) {
            if (responce.result === 'success') {
                $(responce.cities).each(function(){
                    options += '<option value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).attr('city')+'</option>';
                });
                city.html(options);
                city.attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }, 'json'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when you receive the data, you add it to the `options` variable that is global. So, just add this before `$(responce.cities).each(function(){`:

```
options = '';
```

And everything should be fine.

BTW, it's *response*, not *responce*. :)

Answer (score 0):

In function getCities, add `var options='';` as the first line. You're constantly adding to it but never clearing it out, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) `city.attr('disabled', true);` should be `city.prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

2) Try resetting `options` back to an empty string before repopulating it like so:

```
if (responce.result === 'success') {
    options = '';                        
    $(responce.cities).each(function(){
        options += '<option value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).attr('city')+'</option>';
    });

    city.html(options);
    city.attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: No, it should be `.prop()`, not `.attr()`... since jQuery 1.6.

Comment: Whoops, you are correct.  Damn my tunnel vision and only seeing "true".  Edited to comply to Sparky's amazing jQuery standards. :D